# Embedded piwik in rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, iframe, cors, matomo

I am install **piwik** in my local system and integrate with **rails application** for tracking there is problem when i am using **iframe** for Analytic data by piwik i want to show **dashboard** inside my rails app **iframe**. But it's showing errors

**Error**
 Oops… there was a problem during the request. Maybe the server had a temporary issue, or maybe you requested a report with too much data. Please try again. If this error occurs repeatedly please contact your Piwik administrator for assistance.

My config file **config.ini.php**

```
cors_domains[] = "*"
enable_framed_pages = 1
enable_framed_settings = 1

trusted_hosts[] = "192.168.1.101"
trusted_hosts[]= "localhost/analytics/piwik/"
```

**In my firebug Error**

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/analytics/piwik/index.php?date=yesterday&module=Dashboard&action=embeddedIndex&idSite=1%252C2&period=day&idDashboard=1. (Reason: missing token 'x-requested-with' in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).
```

My **erb.slim file** is

```
.panel.panel-primary
  .panel-heading
    h4 Piwik
    iframe height="200"sandbox="allow-scripts" width="600px;" src="http://localhost/analytics/piwik/"
```

Answer (score 2):

If we need **full dashboard** of **piwik** then we simply **login via admin** cred , and go to the **Widgets panel and copy that `<iframe>` code** and paste is to your application.

Example:
[Piwik dashboard integration with iframe CORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL6P8.png)

Your also set user login by its `&token_auth=xxxx`

It will provide you login functionality. Just put the token_auth after end of url.

**In my case user with only view permission.**

```
http://localhost/analytics/piwik/index.php?module=Widgetize&action=iframe&moduleToWidgetize=Dashboard&actionToWidgetize=index&idSite=1&period=week&date=yesterday&token_auth=xxxxxxx
```